# "Entity Framework, ADO .NET y C#"

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Espero que me puedan ayudar ya que intente solucionarlo pero no encontré mucho...
Estoy realizando una aplicación de escritorio Windows Forms, en la cual manejo MVC, Las vistas son un proyecto windows forms, y los modelos y controladores son proyectos de librería de clases, el problema esta en que el proyecto "Modelos" agregue una carpeta llamada EF en donde quiero agregar un elemento de tipo ADO .NET Entity Data Model, pero al momento de crearlo me lanza el siguiente mensaje: "El marco de trabajo de destino del proyecto no contiene ensamblados en tiempo de ejecución de Entity Framework. Revise la información del marco de trabajo de destino en la pagina de propiedades del proyecto" Cabe recalcar que estoy trabajando con .NET 6

Ya intente revisar las versiones y al parecer no hay ningún problema con eso, tambien estuve revisando los paquetes NuGet y al parecer todo esta bien, de igual manera en las propiedades del proyecto, no se a que se deba.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]